# Find $\tan\frac{\alpha}{2},$ if $\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha=\frac{\sqrt7}{2}$ and $\alpha\in(0^\circ;90^\circ)$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find $\tan\dfrac{\alpha}{2},$ if $\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt7}{2}$ and $\alpha\in(0^\circ;90^\circ)$.

So we have $$\sin\alpha+\cos\alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt7}{2}$$ Then $$\sin^2\alpha+\cos^2\alpha+2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=\dfrac74\\2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=\dfrac74-1=\dfrac34\\\sin2\alpha=\dfrac34\\\dfrac{2\tan\alpha}{1+\tan^2\alpha}=\dfrac34\\\tan\alpha=\dfrac{4\pm\sqrt{7}}{3},$$ Is there a more direct approach?

Comment: I see you are doing something like [Weierstrass tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#The_substitution) to convert $\sin 2\alpha$ in terms of $\tan \alpha$, what if you substitute the $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ instead?

Comment: you can use the hint in the below answer and solve a quadratic in $\tan (\alpha/2)$. You get two solutions $\sqrt7 - 2$ and $\frac{\sqrt7 - 2}{3}$ and both are valid for acute $\alpha$

Comment: @MathLover, thank you! I got it. Is the only necessary condition for the solutions to be positive for them to be valid for acute $\alpha$? In your answer you wrote as they are in $(0;1)$, why do we need them to be less than $1$?

Comment: because $\tan 45^0 = 1$ and tan is an increasing function for $(0, \pi / 2)$. So if $\tan (\alpha / 2) \gt 1, \alpha / 2$ would be greater than $45^0$ and so $\alpha$ would be greater than $90^0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$\sin(x)= \sin(2\frac{x}{2})=\frac{2\tan(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})},$
and $\cos(x)= \cos(2\frac{x}{2})=\frac{1-\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}{1+\tan^2(\frac{x}{2})}.$

Try to do this in $\sin(\alpha)+\cos(\alpha)=\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}$,and after some algebraic manipulation you can put $ \tan(\frac{x}{2})=t $ and  then solve the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\beta=\alpha +45^o.$ Then $\sin \beta=\sin \alpha \cos 45^o+\cos \alpha \sin 45^o=(1/\sqrt 2)(\sin \alpha +\cos \alpha)=(\sqrt 7)/(2\sqrt 2).$ And so $\cos \beta=\pm \sqrt {1-\sin^2\beta}=\pm \sqrt {1-7/8}=\pm 1/(2\sqrt 2).$

Now $\cos \alpha =\cos (\beta -45^o)=\cos \beta \cos 45^o+\sin \beta \cos 45^o=(\cos \beta +\sin \beta)/(\sqrt 2)$ and the rest follows.